# What's the deal with Gowther's concealed identity?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

All 7 of the deadly sins were once a team before. It seems Gowther is able to identify everyone on the team, so why isn't anyone able to identify Gowther?

An additional question is why didn't Gowther reveal himself to the group sooner? I don't see why he would hide his presence from his closest allies.

Answer (score 1):

According to the story, the appearances of some of the Sins changed after all that time like Ban, King and Gowther himself (well, Ban did say that he didn't know how Gowther looked in the armor), and besides, since the guys knew about his armor, and since the monster was big and wearing the armor, they probably didn't gave it a second thought.

[image: no identification]

As for the second question, it was because he was waiting for the Sniper (the guy with bow and arrow, for whom Ban went in the beginning), since that was an illusion, he was waiting for him to reveal himself.

[image: waiting]

Comment: I believe you have not accepted my answer, are you unsatisfied with it??

Comment: Your answer seems more speculative than fact driven. IIRC, only King's image from the past differs from the present. Ban and Diana were still recognizable and very similar.

Comment: @krikara Ban appearance changed, he had overgrown hairs. As for your question, no one knew about Gowther's identity (his face is not even in the bounty posters), according to manga, Ban did say he didn't know how he looked, now why would he show his face to one partner but not to other.

Comment: @krikara Sorry for such a late reply, as for the facts, in the bounty poster and the few instances of the Sins in the past, Gowther is always shown wearing his armor, newer without it.

Answer (score 1):

In a more recent chapter, Gowther is revealed to be a:

> puppet.

Merlin gives Gowther magic stabilizing pills in order to regrow his armor.  and when Merlin uses her magic cancelling power, he turns into his "natural" form. It seems clear that his flesh grows due to his magic and, if stabilized for a time, it will grow into an armor.  As the armor is part of Gowther, it is reasonable to think he never took it off.

Comment: lol this was over a year ago! but yeah, now the answer makes sense :)

Comment: There's new info yet again lol